# Sending email using Python and the body of message does not show in outlook

Tags: python, smtplib

I want to write a simple program to send an alert email if I get a low inventory.
I can see the message (`"my_msg"`) if I send it to my Gmail, AOL... but I am not able to see the message in my company email. We are using outlook.
In my code there is a `"the_msg"` that I used to test the body and I could see it in my outlook. But if I replace "the_msg" by `"my_msg"` then I am not able to see `"my_msg"`.  Here is my code:

```
import smtplib
    my_msg = ""
    my_email = "myemail@gmail.com"
    my_pass = "xxxx"
    SUB = 'LOW INVENTORY'
    item_list = [(123, 'ABCD', 15), (124, 'CDE', 5)]
    for item in item_list:
        tool_sap_num = item[0]
        tool_des = item[1]
        tool_qty = item[2]
        my_msg += "SAP#: " + str(tool_sap_num) + ", DESCRIPTION: " + tool_des + ", QTY LEFT:" + str(tool_qty) + ".\n"
    print(my_msg)
    the_msg = "Hello!\nI am Sender"
    print(the_msg)
    connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    connection.ehlo()
    connection.starttls() 
    connection.login(user=my_email, password=my_pass)
    connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email, to_addrs="receiver@mycompany.com", msg="Hello!\nThis is a low inventory list:\n" + my_msg)
    connection.close()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? my_msg is declared at the second line and empty, if you use msg=my _msg it will therefore send an empty email body.

Comment: There is a for loop to generate the my_msg. If I use msg=the_msg then I can see the text in the email body and If I use msg=my_msg then the body not showing at all.

Comment: Try to debug the my_msg string. Send 1 email per element in the my_msg. For example, send: `'SAP'` in the first email, then `'SAP#: 123'`  and so on. Then you will find out which part of the string creates the problem. Then let us know which was it for debugging. For example, could be thath '#' makes a problem or `tool_des` because it wasn't put in str() or '\n' etc.

Comment: tool_des  is a string if you look at the item_list. SAP# is place in double quote so I think it has to be a string. Did a test to print(type(my_msg)) and confirmed it is a string class though. But will try.

Comment: Yes, found it. Thanks for your suggestion. The # and : signs caused the issue. Do you have any idea to fix it?

Comment: I would like to keep the colons in the message. And if you have more than one line then the email is sent successfully but can not receive :(

Comment: Could you please try sending messages with as an raw string? Try: `r"SAP#: "`, so with a leading 'r'. Does that solve the issue?

Comment: No it does not. And I don't understand that if the for loop is finished then my_msg will be two lines of text. I don't receive email at all. Did a debug with the sending email command inside the for loop and I just got email at the first loop ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231930/discussion-between-andreas-and-vann).